# Search a string for dates in perl based on strptime string in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, strptime

I need a way to search any string that contains a valid whole or partial datetime and extract it from that string, based on a strptime format.

For example, if I have:

```
%b%d
```

How can I search this string:

```
"asdbsdjwebzadjabsdmwAug20asdfswelasdsvclasdk"
```

and get some datetime representation of "August 20th" from it?

Are there any modules that allow me to convert a strptime format into a regex and search for it like that?

Any information would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Regexp::Common::time](http://search.cpan.org/~roode/Regexp-Common-time-0.01/time.pm):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Regexp::Common qw(time);

my $str = "asdbsdjwebzadjabsdmwAug20asdfswelasdsvclasdk";
say "matches" if $str =~ $RE{time}{strftime}{-pat => '%b%d'};
```